# Do multiple taming attempts stack in BOTW?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have my eyes set on a nice brown, Seabiscuit looking horse in BOTW. I've got six hearts, and one extra stamina container above the initial wheel. I read [here](http://www.gameskinny.com/rs233/breath-of-the-wild-guide-horse-taming-101) that attempts stack, but this [site](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/77244487#:%7E:text=Taming%20the%20giant%20horse%20takes,need%20a%20lot%20of%20food.) says they don't.

Which is correct?

I've already been eating stamina increasing foods whilst trying to tame it, and temporary stamina boosts to give me a leg up but nothing works in my five attempts so far.

It's night in the game and I'd rather look for Seabiscuit when I can see him and avoid stal-monsters.

If the taming attempts do stack, does it refresh every in-game day? That would be a pain.

Comment: button mashing is your friend. Contrarily at what the game seems to imply you need no pacing in how quickly you press the "soothe" button - just press it as quickly as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the only mechanic to horse taming is that based on the specific horse stats / type you have to press the "soothe" button a specific number of times before running out of stamina. There is nothing else to that, and good button mashing skills will allow you to get every horse with as little as one stamina wheel.

You can get more info in [this Youtube video by Croton](https://youtu.be/t3ZeHlwrGPQ?t=87). Generally speaking, the average horse requires 15 button presses. Royal stallion is 25, and the big black "Ganondor-style" horse requires 30.

Comment: Thanks. Just for full disclosure, and for a good laugh, I was able to nab Seabiscuit after I realized I was pressing the "R" button instead of the "L" button the entire time. But this is useful information.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 well, like I said in my post.... the way the thing is designed actually made me assume the first time I tried that you had to press the "soothe" button with a precise timing based on the horse movement... so I kinda understand your pain. Only later I realized it was pure button mashing. Anyway, the video I linked does cover other horse related mechanics too - like the "bonding" values... so it is a good view if you have time. The same user also posted many other in-depth Zelda BotW videos for many other unclear mechanics - potions, shield values and so on...